# Why does a string that contains HTML entity not displaying character after being ran through htmlspecialchars()

Tags: php, html, html-entities, htmlspecialchars, strip-tags

I have a string of text that is pulled from SQL and then ran through PHP strip_tags and htmlspecialchars because I need to remove all HTML formatting that my user might try to add. It is then displayed in a textarea as well as an uneditable div. The textarea shows the raw HTML entity code (eg. & <) and that's what I want. As for the div, which is a preview of the textarea content, I want it to show the actual character (eg. & <). So, I need the div to convert any special characters to html entities but I want the current HTML entities to be displayed as characters.

This string of text could contain a quite a few different characters because it is technical writings for restaurant equipment so it's not just ampersands and quotation marks. Basically, there are enough that making a list is not an easy option.

This is the function that I run the string through for both the textarea and the preview div:

```
function removeTags($data) {
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
    return $data;
}
```

This is what the textarea displays:

```
This unit has the ability to lower food temperature from 160&#176;F to 38&#176;F, with 110 lbs.
```

An unfortunately the preview div shows the same information but I want the preview div to show the line below while still removing any HTML tags as well as converting any special characters to HTML entities:

> This unit has the ability to lower food temperature from 160°F to 38°F, with 110 lbs.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer with the check mark icon if it helps you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `htmlspecialchars()` function converts certain characters such as `&` and turns them into their HTML entities, such as `&amp;`.

Also, if you want to convert all characters, and not just the ones that `htmlspecialchars()` converts, use `htmlentities()` instead.

Then you can use a `str_replace()` function to show the HTML entities.

For example:

```
$data = "This unit has the ability to lower food temperature from 160°F to 38°F, with 110 lbs.";

$data = "This unit has the ability to lower food temperature from 160°F to 38°F, with 110 lbs.";

function removeTags($data) {
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    $data = htmlentities($data);
    return $data;
}

echo '<textarea cols="95" rows="6">' . str_replace('&', '&amp;', removeTags($data)) . '</textarea>';
echo '<div>' . removeTags($data) . '</div>';
```

In the textarea, the output is:

```
This unit has the ability to lower food temperature from 160&deg;F to 38&deg;F, with 110 lbs.
```

In the div, the output is:

```
This unit has the ability to lower food temperature from 160°F to 38°F, with 110 lbs.
```